# Get string inside parentheses

Tags: sql-server

I want to get string inside parentheses (SQL Server).

My code:

```
declare @Text VARCHAR(100) = '12345 (abcxyz (qwerty), )'
--declare @Text VARCHAR(100) = '12345 (abcxyz, )'

select case when SUBSTRING(@Text, charindex(')', @Text) - 2, 2) = ', '
    then SUBSTRING(@Text, charindex('(', @Text) + 1, len(@Text) - charindex('(', @Text) - 3)
    else SUBSTRING(@Text, charindex('(', @Text) + 1, len(@Text) - charindex('(', @Text) - 1) end
```

Result

```
abcxyz (qwerty), 
abcxyz
```

My expected result:

```
abcxyz (qwerty) -- without comma 
abcxyz
```

Please help! Many thanks!

Comment: What output would you expect for `123 (abc,def),)`?  If `123 (abcdef)` why not wrap a `REPLACE` around your current case expression?

Comment: change the -1 into -3

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply apply replace function in your code.

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(100) = '12345 (abcxyz (qwerty), )'

    SELECT Replace(CASE 
                WHEN SUBSTRING(@Text, charindex(')', @Text) - 2, 2) = ', '
                    THEN SUBSTRING(@Text, charindex('(', @Text) + 1, len(@Text) - charindex('(', @Text) - 3)
                ELSE SUBSTRING(@Text, charindex('(', @Text) + 1, len(@Text) - charindex('(', @Text) - 1)
            END, ',', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Txt VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('12345 (abcxyz (qwerty), )')
,('12345 (abcxyz, )');

SELECT tbl.Txt
      ,positions.*
      ,SUBSTRING(tbl.Txt,FirstOpen+1,LastClose-FirstOpen-2)
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('(',Txt) AS FirstOpen
                  ,LEN(Txt)-CHARINDEX(')',REVERSE(Txt)) AS LastClose
           ) AS positions
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx):

```
declare @Text VARCHAR(100) = '12345 (abcxyz (qwerty), )'

SELECT  STUFF(part1,1,1,''),
        STUFF(LEFT(part2,LEN(part2)-1),1,1,'')
FROM (
    SELECT  PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Text,' ','.'),3) as part1,
            PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Text,' ','.'),3)+' '+PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Text,' ','.'),2) as part2
    ) as p
```

Output:

```
abcxyz  abcxyz (qwerty)
```